# How to read barcode from text file by specified place in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, barcode

> 0000016011071693266104**014482**3 15301 45 VETRO NOVA BLUVETRO NOVA BLUE FLAT STRETCH 115428815150010050 05420 000033 0003
>
> 0000072011076993266101**014687**4 15300 45 VETRO NOVA BLUVETRO NOVA BLUE FLAT STRETCH 115428815160010030 05430 000032 0007

I have a text file which includes many barcode codes line by line, and as you see in above string format are company codes and others show other things.

So how can I get read this text line by line and character by character in C#?

Answer (score 2):

For reading it line by line you can use a `StreamReader` - see for example on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx

Another option is:

```
string[] AllLines = File.ReadAllLines (@"C:\MyFile.txt");
```

This give you all lines in a string array and you can work with them - this uses more memory but is faster... see for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx

When have a line in a string you can split that line for example:

```
string[] MyFields = AllLines[1].Split(null); // since your fields seem to be separated by whitespace
```

The result is that you have the parts of the line in an array and can access for example the second field in the line with `MyFields[1]` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

EDIT - as per comment another option:

IF you exactly know the positions and lengths of your fields you can do this:

```
string MyIdentity = AllLines[1].SubString(1, 5);
```

For MSDN reference see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx

Comment: i have write this code but i could do how to get company Code of each Line ----------------------------------   FileStream akis;
            StreamReader Okuma;
            string Yol = @"C:\barcod\testBarcod.txt";
            akis = new FileStream(Yol, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            Okuma = new StreamReader(akis);
            string satir1 = Okuma.ReadLine();
            string satir2 = Okuma.ReadLine();

Comment: yea i have seen now but mine is not saparate by whitespace. for example 2. to 6. char is identity.how i get it? thanks 

    00000160110716932661040144823

Comment: string MyIdentity = AllLines[1].SubString(1, 5);
i got an error in compile time in substring does not contain

Comment: This means you did not use my code ? In what variable is your line content ? satir2 ? if yes, then use `string MyIdentity = satir2.SubString (1, 5);`

Comment: glad that it works :-) please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You use Microsoft libraries dedicated to files and streams to open a file, and Readline().

Then you use Microsoft libraries dedicated to parsing to parse those lines.

You create, with Microsoft libraries, a regular expression to detect bar codes (not borcod...)

Then you throw away anything that doesn't match your regular expression.

Then you compile and debug (you can use Mono). And voilà, you have a C# program that solves your problem.

Note: you definitely don't need to go "character by character". Microsoft libraries and parsing will be much easier for your simple need.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are after is reading it line-by-line, and character-by-character, then this is a possible solution:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"pathtotextfile.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    foreach (var character in line)
    {
        char individualCharacter = character;
    }
}
```

If you need to know which line and character you are on; you can use a `for` loop instead:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"pathtotextfile.txt");
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    var line = lines[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
    {
        var character = line[j];
    }
}
```

Or use `SelectMany` in LINQ:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"pathtotextfile.txt");
foreach (char individualCharacter in lines.SelectMany(line => line))
{
}
```

Now, as far as my opinion goes, doing it "line by line" and "character by character" seems like a difficult choice to me. If you can tell us what exactly each bit of information is in the barcode, we could help you extract it that way.

Comment: Thank you,i have information about barcode but i cant send from here , do you have any mail so that i can send you?

Comment: for example 2. to 6.(00000160110716932661040144823) char is campany code.how i get it and assign to string? thanks